# How to extract a value from each column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with many rows as below. I just want to extract columns 2,3,5,6; but the third column without the 'chr' prefix:

Input:

```
585     ENST00000417324 chr1    -       34553   36081   36081   36081   3
```

Output:

```
ENST00000417324 1 34553 36081
```

I would use awk as the task is very simple, but I don't know how to get rid of the 'chr' prefix.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could **sub**stitute `chr` at the beginning of the third field with an empty string:

```
awk '{ sub(/^chr/,"",$3); print $2,$3,$5,$6 }' file
```